# Check if ssh client used password or public key auth?

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to check if the current ssh session used a password or public key authentication, without comparing /var/log/auth.log with my current client ip?

And in case if there is no other way how can i get the exact login-time-stamp? `pinky` returns only hh:mm and not a hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question is a negative. That information isn't present anywhere after login. Though if you trust the environment/user you can make the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file specify a variable to set when logging in with a specific key.

For the second question: parse /var/run/utmp yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Would the [lastlog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lastlog) command provide the info you want

```
lastlog --user luser
Username         Port     From             Latest
luser            pts/1    2a00:14f0:e090:8 Sun Jun  9 16:20:02 +0100 2013
```

Comment: ty, sadly i cant toggle both answers as "accepted and helpful"